# Regex match uppercase character until a digit is encountered

Tags: regex

I'm trying to catch a string containing two or more uppercase characters.  The end of the string is always a number. Sometimes there might be line breaks between the letters and the number, sometimes not. Here's what I have so far:

```
[A-Z-ÅÖÄ\s]+[^\d]
```

The engine is based on javascript.

Example:

Input:

```
ABC ABCDE XYZ
1
EFG XYZ ABC 2
not me
EFG ABC
3
```

Output:
    match1: ABC ABCDE XYZ
    match2: EFG XYZ ABC
    match3: EFG ABC

Comment: Please give one or two concrete examples of input and expected output.

Comment: You should probably try your currently accepted answer with input `"ABC fail @!% 1"` (and then try my answer with the same input), unless your examples are all edge cases and any other chars are allowed in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in Javascript:

```
/^[A-Z]{2}[^]*?(?=\s*\d+$)/gm
```

[ReGEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZdpZS/4)

**RegEx Description:**

- `^` - Line start
- `[A-Z]{2}` - Match 2 uppercase English alphabets
- `[^]*?` - Match 0 or more of any characters (including newline), lazy
- `(?=\s*\d+$)` - Lookahead that asserts we have 0 or more space followed by a 1 or or more digits in the end.

**Code Demo:**

```js
var str = `ABC ABCDE XYZ
1
EFG XYZ ABC 2
not me
EFG ABC
3`;

var re = /^[A-Z]{2}[^]*?(?=\s*\d+$)/gm;

var m = str.match(re);

console.log(m);
```

Comment: If you only want to allow uppercase letters with whitespace then use: `/^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z\s]*?(?=\s*\d+$)/gm` regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[A-Z]{2}( *[A-Z])*(?=\s\d$)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/rt3gXHxFzq).

Or this multi-lingual version (YMMV in JavaScript):

```
^\p{Lu}{2}( *\p{Lu})*(?=\s\d$)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/hjaENctqLP).

This handles all uppercase letters from all languages (as suggested by your attempt that includes `ÅÖÄ` characters).

Neither will match `"ABC fail 1"`.

Comment: OP wrote engine is based in Javascript so `\p{Lu}` may not work.

Comment: @anub just checked and it doesn't work in JS, and yet JS allows `[^]` :/